# Which joomla extensions should be installed on every joomla site

Tags: php, joomla

I want to know that as a web developer which joomla extensions one should install onany website to start with.

E,g i i always install JCE editor , ExtPlorer , joomMyadmin and then i proceed further. Any more suggestions

Comment: Not sure if discussion-type questions like this are allowed there.  They are generally discouraged on SE sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Admin Tools and Akeeba Backup - both from https://www.akeebabackup.com/

I am also a fan of multiple NoNumber extensions such as Advanced Module Manager, Cache Cleaner, and Admin Bar Docker - http://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/

Comment: I like their "Nothing Module" which does nothing ha ha. Must have been tough to code